# Preserve White Space

Tags: html, google-apps-script, sidebar

I want to preserve white space to keep every column align properly.
But sidebar auto remove any extra space, could someone give me some advise on this.

[Google Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otRpI.jpg)

````
function Test1() {

var lineBrk = "<br />"
var aValues = "```"+lineBrk+
"BLB001| APPLE | O/B   |   100.00"+lineBrk+
"AG010 | ORANGE| O/B   |   125.25"+lineBrk+
"B123  | KIWI  | O/B   |    95.00"+lineBrk+
"```"

 // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(aValues);

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);

}
````

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951133/when-to-use-nbsp

Comment: Why not just format as HTML and use `display: table; table-layout: fixed` to set cells at the same size?

Comment: @BrianBennett
I am new to google app, could you show me some simple example how to use the method you mentioned.
And secondly, I need to copy paste that result to chatting app, and most chatting app don't recognized complex format.

Comment: And how could I change font to monospace in Sidebar?

Comment: @Lee I added a response below about how to build HTML for your table which keeps columns spaced evenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidebars are created using the Google Apps Script HTML service, that means that they use [html](/questions/tagged/html) and that is why Serge included a link to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16951133/1595451) regarding the use of `&nbsp;`. Another alternative is to enclose the text lines on `<pre>` tags.

Below is an adaptation of the code that builds the html output to work on the stack snippet.

```js
var lineBrk = "</pre><br />"
var aValues = 
"<pre>BLB001| APPLE | O/B   |   100.00"+lineBrk+
"<pre>AG010 | ORANGE| O/B   |   125.25"+lineBrk+
"<pre>B123  | KIWI  | O/B   |    95.00"+lineBrk;

document.write(aValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to display plaintext, Ruben's answer above would work. If you want some kind of formatting, using simple HTML layout styles will help.

You could interpret your table example as the following HTML:

```html
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BLB001</div>
    <div class="col">Apple</div>
    <div class="col">0/B</div>
    <div class="col">100.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">AG010</div>
    <div class="col">Orange</div>
    <div class="col">0/B</div>
    <div class="col">125.25</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">B123</div>
    <div class="col">Kiwi</div>
    <div class="col">0/B</div>
    <div class="col">95.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, either in a `style` tag or a linked CSS file, set the display:

```css
#table { 
  display: table; 
  table-layout:fixed; 
  width: 300px;  /* This could be any width you'd like */
  font-family:monospace;
}
.row { display: table-row; }
.col { display: table-cell; }
```

You can also set borders, if you want them. The nice thing about using this method is that you can populate any number of rows or cells using an apps script loop if your data is variable.

[Here's a very simple CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/gWKMEg) showing the layout only.

Comment: I am new to everything, I like to learn more regarding your method.
I I try to assign your script into aValues, but not working, can you show me the correct method to do it.