# Rogue &nbsp in Wordpress blog

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a weird problem with [my Wordpress blog](https://kogi.gr).

`&nbsp` is inserted right after the `<body>` tag. There's no `&nbsp` in the `header.php` file, though. It's just the `<body>` tag and then a `<div>`.

Is there any way to stop this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT |

This is the `header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="profile" href="<?php echo esc_url( 'gmpg.org/xfn/11' ); ?>">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
   </head>

   <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
      <div id="wrapper">

      <?php do_action('__before_header') ; ?>

      <?php hu_get_template_part('parts/header-main'); ?>

      <?php do_action('__after_header') ; ?>

      <div class="container" id="page">
          <div class="container-inner">
              <?php do_action('__before_main') ; ?>
              <div class="main">
                  <div class="main-inner group">
                      <?php do_action('__before_content') ; ?>
```

Comment: of course, it could be done using js. but will be right to found where its generating and delete just from there. can you provide php file, or section of it, where starts body tag?

Comment: I just added it. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: can you show ud the outputted HTML as well? just so that we can see the &nbsp

Comment: there might be a function, that is hooking in and adding this - but it seems weird.

Comment: try to delete all spaces after <body> tag, like `
      <body <?php body_class(); ?>><div id="wrapper">` . but it seems you provided wrong header.php, because in the site you provided generating `head` tag codes directly after `body` tag

Comment: When I view the source, there's no `&nbsp`. When I use the Developer Tools in Chrome, there is one right after the `<body>` tag.

Comment: also, try to delete all spaces beetween `head` and `meta`, like `<head><meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">`

Comment: do u use some `hook/plugin/js` to move `head` part directly after `body` tag?

Comment: That's what I'm looking into right now.. I didn't write the theme, I use a child. It seems to be using js and hooks. It's the Hueman theme.

Comment: it's can't  be just guessed. first, delete all cache from plugins, then deactivate them. if the problem don't dissapear, then it's generating theme. after you should to go through the theme files and find where you got it

Comment: also, before doing steps above, did you deleted all spaces as I said?

Comment: Oops! I'd deleted the spaces in the parent theme's `header.php`! Now I deleted them in the child and it's fixed! Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is `&nbsp;`?**

It's good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951149/8053001)

**How to remove `&nbsp;` from html?**

You should find beetwen which `html tags` it's occured and delete all spaces which are between that tags.

Considering discussion on your question: after `body` tag you got `&nbsp;`. So, just removing spaces after `<body>` from `header.php` of your wordpress `child` and `parent` themes stops rendering `&nbsp;`.